# Why is a $p(\sigma^2)\sim\text{IG(0.001, 0.001)}$ prior on variance considered weak?

Tags: bayesian, multilevel-analysis, prior

### Background

One of the most commonly used weak prior on variance is the inverse-gamma with parameters $\alpha =0.001, \beta=0.001$ [(Gelman 2006)](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf).

However, this distribution has a 90%CI of approximately $[3\times10^{19},\infty]$.

```
library(pscl)
sapply(c(0.05, 0.95), function(x) qigamma(x, 0.001, 0.001))

[1] 3.362941e+19          Inf
```

From this, I interpret that the $IG(0.001, 0.001)$ gives a low probability that variance will be very high, and the very low probability  that variance will be less than 1 $P(\sigma<1|\alpha=0.001, \beta=0.001)=0.006$.

```
pigamma(1, 0.001, 0.001)
[1] 0.006312353
```

### Question

Am I missing something or is this actually an informative prior?

*update* to clarify, the reason that I was considering this 'informative' is because it claims very strongly that the variance is enormous and well beyond the scale of almost any variance ever measured.

*follow-up* would a meta-analysis of a large number of variance estimates provide a more reasonable prior?

---

### Reference

Gelman 2006. [Prior distributions for variance parameters in
hierarchical models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf). Bayesian Analysis 1(3):515–533

Comment: A "true" noninformative prior is not a distribution. So there's no prior probability such as P(sigma<1).

Comment: Does $\beta$ here correspond to scale or rate? E.g. in R, would it be `invgamma::dinvgamma(sigma, shape = 0.01, scale = 0.01)` or `invgamma::dinvgamma(sigma, shape = 0.01, rate = 0.01)`?

Comment: @bob scale, I believe

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using the inverse gamma distribution, we get:

$$p(\sigma^2|\alpha,\beta) \propto (\sigma^2)^{-\alpha-1} \exp(-\frac{\beta}{\sigma^2})$$

You can see easily that if $\beta \rightarrow 0$ and $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ then the inverse gamma will approach the Jeffreys prior.  This distribution is called "uninformative" because it is a proper approximation to the Jeffreys prior

$$p(\sigma^2) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

Which is uninformative for scale parameters [see page 18 here for example](http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/prior.pdf), because this prior is the only one which remains invariant under a change of scale  (note that the approximation is not invariant).  This has a indefinite integral of $\log(\sigma^2)$ which shows that it is improper if the range of $\sigma^2$ includes either $0$ or $\infty$.  But these cases are only problems in the maths - not in the real world.  Never actually observe infinite value for variance, and if the observed variance is zero, you have perfect data!.  For you can set a lower limit equal to $L>0$ and upper limit equal $U<\infty$, and your distribution is proper.

While it may seem strange that this is "uninformative" in that it prefers small variance to large ones, but this is only on one scale.  You can show that $\log(\sigma^2)$ has an improper uniform distribution.  So this prior does not favor any one scale over any other

Although not directly related to your question, I would suggest a "better" non-informative distribution by choosing the upper and lower limits $L$ and $U$ in the Jeffreys prior rather than $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Usually the limits can be set fairly easily with a bit of thought to what $\sigma^2$ actually means in the real world.  If it was the error in some kind of physical quantity - $L$ cannot be smaller than the size of an atom, or the smallest size you can observe in your experiment.  Further $U$ could not be bigger than the earth (or the sun if you wanted to be really conservative).  This way you keep your invariance properties, and its an easier prior to sample from: take $q_{(b)} \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(\log(L),\log(U))$, and then the simulated value as $\sigma^{2}_{(b)}=\exp(q_{(b)})$.

Comment: +1 for not only answering the question, but also providing useful advice.

Comment: +1 - uniform for $log(\sigma)$ on a "big" range is often a good choice. For the variance components of a hierarchical model I think you can still get into near-impropriety of the posterior if the range is too large since you're approaching Jeffrey's again. But of course it's a simpler fix - just don't pick huge intervals :)

Comment: @JMS - in a heirarchical setting, the data do not "squash" the singularity at 0 (i.e. a level 2 variance could be zero).  So the prior for small values matters.  $Beta_{2}(1,1)$ is a good level 2 and higher variance prior (I think it also has been called a "half Cauchy", it is similar to $F_{1,1}$-distribution).  It has "fat tails" and is "data-robust" in that, if prior and likelihood conflict, the likelihood wins.  Also $Beta_{2}(0,0)$ is the jeffreys prior.

Comment: @probabilityislogic thanks for the explanation. If I understand, the gamma is nice theoretically because its rage is $[0,\infty]$ and because it is conjugate to the normal, but in application these features are not generally required. But what is the difference between sampling from $\sigma\sim exp(U(log(L),log(U))$ and $\sigma\sim U(L,U)$?

Comment: @probabilityislogic Not familiar with your notation, are you referring to the beta prime? If so it's an interesting choice. Not the half Cauchy though; that's just the Cauchy restricted to $(0, \infty)$. But the beta prime with $\alpha=1, \beta=1/2$ has been called the "quasi Cauchy" IIRC

Comment: I should say, the convolution of the beta prime with $\alpha=1, \beta=1/2$ and the normal has been called "quasi-Cauchy" (I think). It's got a spike at zero and Cauchy-like tails.

Comment: @JMS - I am referring "beta prime".  And it is the "odds ratio" of a beta distribution.  You can show using this, that its a ratio of two gamma's with same scale.  So I think (1,1) it would be the "square" of a cauchy distribution $\left(\frac{Z_1}{Z_2}\right)^2=\frac{\chi^{2}_{1}(1)}{\chi_{2}^{2}(1)}=\beta_2(1,1)$.

Comment: @David - if you have a highly informative likelihood, then the uniform won't be much difference.  The uniform prior depends on which scale you use.  e.g. $\sigma \sim U(L,U)$ is flat on $\sigma$, but not flat on $\sigma^2$ or $\sigma^{-2}$.  So something about using the "scale", and not the variance or precision must mean something.  The jeffreys prior looks the same regardless of which you pick (invariant), as long as $L$ and $U$ are transformed accordingly.

Comment: @ probabilityislogic Ah cool I see the connection. $\beta_2(1,1)$ would have lighter tails than a Cauchy though, no? I think that was why $\beta_2(1, 1/2)$ was called the quasi-Cauchy since they've got the same polynomial tails. The literature goes back a ways on that specific prior but I first ran across it in Griffin & Brown "Bayesian adaptive lassos with non-convex penalization" in the context of the exponential-gamma prior for variance parameters (which I think are a special case of $\beta_2$).

Answer (score 10):

It's pretty close to flat.  Its median is 1.9 E298, almost the largest number one can represent in double precision floating arithmetic.  As you point out, the probability it assigns to any interval that isn't really huge is really small.  It's hard to get less informative than that!

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I have been running into convergence problems and I was surprised that so many of the variables I work with have means is < 1000 (i.e. if something is >1000 g it is measured in kg), and the variances are on about the same order of magnitude. So, I am realizing that I need more priors that incorporate this information even if I don't really have a good prior knowledge of its value or how it is partitioned.

Comment: Depending on the model, your posterior might be very close to improper using this prior