# error when running JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

In an attempt to learn JAGS I am trying to fit a line to data points. The data points have errors in both directions i.e. along the xaxis and yaxis.

Here is my model:

```
N = length(x)
DataSet = list(x = x, y = y, xerr = 0.155, yerr = 0.29, N = N)

# Define the model:
modelGregory = "
model {
  for ( i in 1:N ) {
    xtrue[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
    ymodel[i] <- alpha + beta * xtrue[i]
    ytrue[i] ~ dnorm(ymodel[i], sigma)
  }

  for ( i in 1:N ){
    x[i] ~ dnorm( xtrue[i], xerr )
    y[i] ~ dnorm( ytrue[i], yerr )
  }
  mu ~ dnorm(0, 10)
  tau ~ dnorm(0, 50)
  alpha ~ dnorm(0, 10)
  beta ~ dnorm(0, 10)
  sigma ~ dt(0, 5, 1) # cauchy distribution with dof = 1
}
"

library('rjags')

# Run the chains
jags <-jags.model(textConnection(modelGregory), data = DataSet, 
              n.chains = 3, n.adapt = 100)

# update(jags, n.iter = 500)

# jags.samples(jags, c('alpha', 'beta', 'sigma'), 300)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Compiling model graph
   Resolving undeclared variables
   Allocating nodes
Graph information:
   Observed stochastic nodes: 30
   Unobserved stochastic nodes: 35
   Total graph size: 109

Initializing model
Deleting model

Error in jags.model(textConnection(modelGregory), data = DataSet, n.chains = 3,  : 
  Error in node xtrue[1]
Invalid parent values
```

Can someone please explain to me why I am getting an error?
I believe that the error might be because of `tau`. In STAN, I'd define `tau` as `real<lower=0> tau;` If the error is because of `tau` how do I fix it?

Also, I would really appreciate it if someone explains to me what is `Compiling model graph` and `graph information`.

Note that the 2 last lines of the script are a comment because I know the error is coming from `jags <- jags.model( ... )`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error message says

```
  Error in node xtrue[1]
Invalid parent values
```

the `xtrue` variable has invalid parent values, so let's check what is it

```
xtrue[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
...
mu ~ dnorm(0, 10)
tau ~ dnorm(0, 50)
```

$\tau$ cannot have a normal distribution since it is a [precision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183522/antonym-of-variance/183523#183523) parameter, i.e. inverse of variance, and **variance cannot be negative**, while you use as a prior for it a symmetric distribution centered at zero...

In such case you should use a distribution that does not allow negative values (e.g. truncated normal, as noticed by *Rasmus Bååth*, or gamma). See also [Andrew Gelmans blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2006/02/06/prior_distribut/), his paper ["Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models"](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf) (2006, *Bayesian Analysis*), or [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8104/why-is-a-p-sigma2-sim-textig0-001-0-001-prior-on-variance-considered-w/8108).

Comment: So as I anticipated, the error is from `tau`. In STAN, I'd put `real<lower=0> tau`. How can I write this is in JAGS? Do you suggest I use a prior other than a normal distribution for tau? I appreciate help on the statistics part also.

Comment: Just to get it to run, start by replacing `tau ~ dnorm(0, 50)` with `tau ~ dnorm(0, 50) T(0, )`, and similarly with the `sigma` parameter I guess. This truncates the distribution so that it is never lower than `0`.

Comment: @RasmusBååth Thank you. Now it is working. However, I'd like to know your opinion statistics wise. Which one is statistically correct (1) to use a truncated distribution or (2) to use a positive distribution (Such as the gamma distribution?)

Comment: @po6 both cases are correct, those are just a different priors that can be used.

Comment: @RasmusBååth can you take a look to my question asked here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184673/jags-error-in-hierarchical-model. I am using a model defined on your site to get the model I want. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim, can you please take a look at my other question now: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184673/jags-error-in-hierarchical-model%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B