# Derive the prior on variance scale if uniform prior placed on logarithm scale

Tags: bayesian, prior

In page 64 of [Bayesian Data Analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/) by Gelman et.al. they write

> ... sensible vague prior density for µ and σ, assuming prior independence of location and scale parameters, is uniform on ($\mu$, $\log~\sigma$) or, equivalently, $p(\mu, \sigma^2) \propto 1/\sigma^2$.

Also in page 87 of [The BUGS Book](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-the-bugs-book/) ([pdf download](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/bugsbook_chapter5.pdf)) they discuss the equivalence of the Jeffreys prior to the uniform on the scale:

> ... the Jeﬀreys prior is $p_J(\sigma) \propto \sigma^{-1}$, which in turn means that $p_J(\sigma^k) \propto \sigma^{-k}$ for any choice of power k. ... we note that the Jeﬀreys prior is equivalent to $p_J(log \sigma^k) \propto constant$.

I have understood this to mean that a uniform prior on $\log \sigma^2$ should be $\propto 1/\sigma^2$. I have been unable to derive this. This is my attempt (with a nod to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/creating-a-uniform-prior-on-the-logarithmic-scale#415239)):

\begin{align}
\text{Let}~ Y =& \log \sigma^2 \\
p(Y) \propto& 1 \\
\frac{dY}{d\sigma^2} =& 2/\sigma
\end{align}

Then to get the distribution on the $\sigma^2$ scale:

\begin{align}
\text{If}~ X =& \sigma^2 \\
\text{then}~ p(X) =& p(Y) |\frac{dY}{d\sigma^2}| \\
  =& 1 \times 2/\sigma \\
  \propto & 1/\sigma
\end{align}

Where have I gone wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is going from $\text{Let}~ Y = \log \sigma^2$ to $\dfrac{dY}{d\sigma^2} = 2/\sigma$

You should have: $\dfrac{dY}{d\sigma^2} = 1/{\sigma^2}$ (simple derivative of a logarithm)

though perhaps you tried  $\dfrac{dY}{d\sigma} = 2\sigma \frac{1}{\sigma^2}= 2/{\sigma}$ (chain rule).

This gives you: $\text{If}~ X = \sigma^2 \text{ then } p(X) \propto  1/{\sigma^2}$ for the improper prior.

It is worth noting that $\log(\sigma^k)=k\log(\sigma)$ and this indicates why something similar happens for all powers of the standard deviation.

Comment: oh darn it! Yes you diagnosed my mistake. Thanks Henry